# Redirect в CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter, redirect

Для чего используется redirect?

Comment: Казалось бы, при чём тут MySQL и PHP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$remember = (bool) $this->input->post('remember');
  if ($this->ion_auth->login($this->input->post('identity'), $this->input->post('password'), $remember))
  {
    redirect('admin', 'refresh');
  }
  else
  {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message',$this->ion_auth->errors());
    redirect('admin/user/login', 'refresh');
  }
```

Смотри пример. Если авторизация прошла, перенаправляем пользователя на страницу admin. Если нет, то перенаправляем на admin/user/login. Другими словами redirect - это перенаправление.

Answer (score 1):

Причин для использования редиректа может быть масса: 
например редирект с одного сайта на другой или
с одной страницы на другую.
К примеру ваш сайт сменил домен old.domain.com и вы бы хотели чтобы люди при обращении к нему попадали на new.domain.com
Эти редиректы самые распространенные и имеют код 301

Еще один вид популярного редиректа 404 - это когда пользователь пытается достучаться до несуществующего адреса на вашем сайте, в таком случае все пользователи будут направлены на страницу "Извините но такой странице не существует"

Не менее распространенный редирект 403 - данный код означает, что пользователь не имеет прав доступа к данной странице.

Еще пример: пользователя надо отправить на определенную страницу сайта после определенных действий. К примеру пользователь оплатил заказ и мы делаем редирект на страницу "Спасибо за вашу покупку"

И таких вавриантов может быть масса.

Более подробно вы можете почитать [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP)

Важным моментом является то что если мы осуществляем редирект на php то не должно быть отправленно никаких данных пользователю для вывода, даже пустой строки иначе редирект не произойдет.
Почитать можно [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php)